# POST data from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, post, base64, content-type

I send datas via POST from a C# application to PHP. For content-type i use application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Works fine.

Now i want to send a base64 code. I found out that in application/x-www-form-urlencoded it remove special signs like +. That will destroy the base64 code. I have read about urlencoding and urldecoiding. But in my opinion it seems not a acceptable way. Also the PHP function of urldecode don't change the sighn + correctly back.

Is there a other good way to send data via POST, maybe with an other content-type? How about application/json or application/xml or text/plain?
How it have looks like in PHP?

The most important thing is to prevent the urlencoding/urldecoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded must be urlencoded, it's specifically designed for that.

If you urlencode the base64 data, then on PHP it will be restored without the need to use any other function, just access to the post variables as usual.